# if(!isset($_GET['id']) with to different options with the same variable

Tags: php

I have this code:   it works fine

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || $_GET['id'] != '1000'){

  header('Location: http://website.com?id=1000');
  exit; 

 }  
?>
```

what i need is to add a second value  like this

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET['id']) || $_GET['id'] != '1000' or $_GET['id'] !='2000'){

     header('Location: http://website.com?id=1000');
      exit; 

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Call isset multiple times and use the logical operator between the results

Comment: @Snake-hh You should delete those comments to avoid confusion. I've made an answer that demonstrates it, and shows the functional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in_array` and add all the values you want to check against into the array:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !in_array($_GET['id'], array('1000', '2000'))){
    echo 'not 1k or 2 k';
} else {
    echo 'is 1k or 2k';
}
```

Functional example: https://3v4l.org/Q2uao

Comment: it works but not as it should be, it activates the action many times

Comment: Is this in a loop? Please add more code, you can put a `die`, `break`, or `exit` to stop the execution when this condition is met. There is nothing here that would cause a loop.

Comment: Before the `header` put `exit(var_dump($_GET['id']));` and provide the output.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your condition in to two parts.

1. First use the !isset condition and then
2. Put the rest of condition inside if condition

Your Code Look like this :

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  if($id == 1000 || $id == 2000) {
     // Action
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is doing not equals.

Comment: it didn't work, cause when there's other value  .php?id=3456  it does nothing,,

Comment: @Snake-hh you are specificly having values list or simply getting the values of `integers` in the `id` parameter. @Alex sorry hihihi

Comment: bro its not my question ;)